# Download xlsx with request w/pem cert

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, request, openssl

Im having abit of issue downloading an xlsx file over https.

Here my code to scrape the sight to get the download url, but its seems to redirect me to a new site. but when i put the link in my browswer, it downloads the file straight away.

Is there something im doing wrong?

here is the code i used for scraping the site:

```
import contextlib
import OpenSSL.crypto
import os
import requests
import ssl
import tempfile
import http.client
import shutil
from OpenSSL import crypto
import pem
import html2text

url = "https://signonssl.site.com"
base_url = "basedownloadurl"

p12_cert = "cert_path"
password = "password"

@contextlib.contextmanager
def pfx_to_pem(p12_path, pfx_password):
    ''' Decrypts the .p12 file to be used with requests. '''
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem') as t_pem:
        f_pem = open(t_pem.name, 'wb')
        pfx = open(p12_path, 'rb').read()
        p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, pfx_password)
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
        ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()
        f_pem.close()
        yield t_pem.name

with pfx_to_pem(p12_cert, password) as cert:

     html_response = requests.get(url, cert=cert).content.decode("utf-8")
     htmlconv = html2text.html2text(html_response).split("name")[1]
     dl_link = htmlconv.split(")")[0].split("(")[1]

     dl = requests.get(dl_link, cert=cert, stream=True, allow_redirects=False)

     output = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
     output.write(dl.content)
     output.close()
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks!
Pon

Comment: When i print out the dl.content, its comes through as a HTML, with the following:   b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>302 Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Found</h1>\n<p>The document has moved <a href="https://signon.site.com">here</a>.</p>\n</body></html>\n'
which basically redirect to a login page to auth the cert or username/password, but when i just place the link directly into the browser, it downloads straight away

Comment: You can try selenium if it suits your need.